# format of certificate Issuer string in SAML reponse

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, saml-2.0

When signing a SAML Assertion with the private key of an SSL certificate, what is the format of the certificate's Issuer string?

```
 Dim ResponseIssuer As XmlElement 
 ResponseIssuer = doc.CreateElement("Issuer", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion")
 Dim issuerFormat As XmlAttribute
 issuerFormat = doc.CreateAttribute("Format")
 issuerFormat.Value = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity"
 ResponseIssuer.Attributes.Append(issuerFormat)
 ResponseIssuer.InnerText = IssuerString    ' <= here
 <snip>
```

When I examine the Issuer in MMC Certificates snap-in, this is the display in the window's text-area:

```
 CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
 O  = DigiCert Inc
 C = US
```

Copying and pasting that string, including carriage-returns does not seem to work. Is only a particular chunk of it required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ResponseIssuer is not the issuer of the signing certificate, but the issuer of the SAML Response message. This is the entityID of the entity sending the Response

Comment: Thank you for that clarification. Is the `entityID` specified on the certificate as one of the "Subject Alternative Names"?

Comment: neither nor! As Stefan already pointed out the information of the certificate is totally unrelated to the entityID SAML protocol messages. The entityID is typically defined in the IdP SAML meta data, which is provided to the SPs so that they can check the issuer. An entityID could be a random string, some profiles (like the eGov one) requires the entityID to be an URL. You may have a look at the document "Metadata for the OASIS Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML) V2.0" which defines the entityID type.